# Create a share intent that also allows to save a document on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to create a share intent that gives the user the option to save the file somewhere in the device? Like an intent with [ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).
My situation is the following: I have a file that is NOT visible to the user, saved in the app's documents folder via [getExternalFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), and I want to allow the user to either share that file, or save it directly in an accessible folder (it would be nice to suggest the user a path, like the file explorer opening directly in the public Download folder, but it is not needed). All of this should be wrapped inside the share intent, as I am only allowed to edit that as of now.
The code looks something like this:

```
String packageName = Utils.currentContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Utils.currentContext, packageName + ".provider", file);
        Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intentShareFile.setType(type);
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text);
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        intentShareFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Sharing file");
        Utils.currentActivity.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

I tried working with [putExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable)) as well as [addCategory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#addCategory(java.lang.String)) with no success.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read the [tour] and the [help], and feel free to ask on [meta] if you have any questions :)

Comment: "one of the options would be to save the document" -- you said that you already saved the document ("it's a file I saved using getExternalFilesDir(String dir) method").

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah, I should have explained myself better. I need the file to be visible to the user. I have limitations on how to solve the problem, I can work on the share functionality but not how we can save files. Files are saved in directories that are not visible to the user, and I'd need to add the possibility to save documents wherever the user wants, via the share menu.

Comment: "I am a bit lost on how to achieve my goal" -- stock Android's share sheet does not have an option for this. It's possible that there are some devices whose share sheet offers this out of the box or via some manufacturer-specific options.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh, that's a bummer. Thank you for your help

Comment: @AlessandroPalumbo I'm also in the same boat. I want to let the user save the media wherever they want from the share menu. Eg:They want to save image from WhatsApp chat to ~/Downloads folder via the share menu. Have you figured this out?

Comment: @duplex143 unfortunately not, I tried with no success.

Comment: Did you figure this  out?

Comment: @Jono not really unfortunately. It was not implemented in the project afaik